# I have installed Ubuntu, but want to re-install windows Vista

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista

I have found my experience of Ubuntu too demanding, and want to re-install Windows Vista. However, the installation disc says I need NTFS. When I then click the reformat option, I get an Error Message :0x80004005.
I have tried this Forum, but I don't understand Ubuntu terminology - I can't find my way round this OS. I've looked everywhere for DISC UTILITY to see if I can reformat the HDD from within Ubuntu, but I can't find it - it's not an option. Can anyone  help in terms I can understand???
I have a Windows installation disc, but it won't work for the reason given above.

Comment: As my Windows installation disc won't install, that part of the answer was not helpful. Sadly, I found some of this answer difficult to understand - "Type into the terminal....." is an example. I really found myself very lost when experienced people were trying to help. There was an assumption that I was familiar with this OS, but I am not. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

DONT PANIC Pal,you cannot reformat your ubuntu partition from within ubuntu.
just try inserting a bootable usb/dvd of UBUNTU, then work your way around to the installation menu of the Ubuntu,

when there appears 'Try Ubuntu' AND 'Install'

Click on Install,

Then goto 'Try Something else', you will see partitions, if it is the full reisntallation you want, then click on all of it one by one and delete the partitions there, then reformat them there with NTFS, then exit the installation, remember DO NOT GO FURTHER OR YOU WILL AGAIN END UP INSTALLING THE UBUNTU, now you take ubuntu bootable medium OUT and put in the Windows Vista bootable dvd/usb and install it like a boss. :D Hope it helps. :D

Comment: They can just use the Windows disk to erase the partitions and use the entire drive.  No need to complicate by saying "Do these steps but then don't hit next on it anymore".  They could also use `gparted` from the "Try Ubuntu" option to just delete partitions.

Comment: Excuse me pal, you gave me a minus 1 without reading the whole question thoroughly, please read the question first, it says that the person could not delete the partitions through the 'windows' bootable disk and that is the error he got, moreover, yes! it can be with the 'try ubuntu' but seems like the person was a beginner and he does not know his way around the ubuntu  :) .. thanks anyways ..

Comment: I have got the the partition window, but 'delete' is not an option offered.

Comment: I have got the the partition window, but 'delete' is not an option offered. I am offered:- Ext 4 journaling file system; Ext 3 journaling file system; Ext 2 file system; btrfs journaling file system; JFS journaling file system; XFS journaling file system; FAT16 file system; FAT32 file system; swap area; physical volume for encryption and (finally) do not use the partition. What do I do?

Comment: @SHYMAD actually I read the question, then I read your answer, and you overcomplicate - saying "Try Something Else" in the *installer* then say "Don't go further".  You could reduce the complexity by saying "Hit Try ubuntu, open `gparted`, right click the partition, hit "delete"."  In any case, this is a dupe of another question, so answers are at that point irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, gparted is another Ubuntu item I cannot find, mentioned in other solutions. Hence my 'last resort' question!

Comment: My problem is solved. I was able to use the Windows installation disc to remove the partitions - no need to reformat. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case, if you found Ubuntu too demanding, did you check other flavors that embed a UX that might be more in line with your computer habits ?
One can try Xubuntu or VoyagerLive (a full featured Xubuntu based distro) : http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=voyager

Comment: I'm not sure this is a legitimate answer to the question.

Comment: As I said,  "just in case", my answer is considering the first part of the sentence :  _I have found my experience of Ubuntu too demanding_